# Find the matrix for a Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

> If $T\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 1\\ -4\end{pmatrix}$, $T \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ -4\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, and $T \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$ what is $T \begin{pmatrix}-2\\ -4\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$?

So I tried to insert all the values one at a time and multiply them accordingly. By doing that I got \begin{pmatrix}8\\ 16\\ 0\end{pmatrix} but only the top number was correct.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following identity to evaluate the transformation of $(-2,-4,0)$.

$$T \left(\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -4 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \right)=-2T \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \right)-4T \left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \right)$$